# Highchart Funnel for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

Anyone ever used Highchart Funnel for Angular?

I use the highchart-ng (https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng), but to funnel not works.

My code using ng-highchart is:

```
$scope.chartSalesFunnel = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'funnel',
            marginRight: 100
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                },
                neckWidth: '30%',
                neckHeight: '25%'

                //-- Other available options
                // height: pixels or percent
                // width: pixels or percent
            }
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Unique users',
        data: [
            ['Website visits', 15654],
            ['Downloads', 4064],
            ['Requested price list', 1987],
            ['Invoice sent', 976],
            ['Finalized', 846]
        ]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Funnel chart type requires the extra Funnel module, as described [in the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.funnel).

You can include it like this:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1805/) of your code with this module included.